# Parse HTML, multiple classes

Tags: html, powershell

I want to create a PowerShell script to get infromation from a website.
I am trying to find the first occurence of the following HTML tag of the website:

```html
<div class="dDoNo gsrt"><span data-dobid="hdw">Text I want to find</span></div>
```

I am using the following PowerShell code without success, gives me not output:

```bsh
$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest "https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&q=define+Text"
($WebResponse.ParsedHtml.GetElementsByTagName(‘div’) | Where {
    $_.ClassName -eq ‘dDoNo’
}).InnerText
```

To be more precise:
I am trying to get the definition of a word by scraping the HTML from google and am using this class as a base:
[googleDictionaryAPI class](https://github.com/meetDeveloper/googleDictionaryAPI/blob/master/app.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ansgar to pointing me to the correct solution.

The main problem was that the response I got from Invoke-WebRequest was different than the one i got from a browser. The solution was to define a UserAgent when invoking the request:

```
$WebResponse = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&q=define+Text" -UserAgent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36")

($WebResponse.ParsedHtml.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName('div') | Where {
    $_.ClassName -match '\bdDoNo\b'
}).InnerText
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you need to call `GetElementsByTagName()` on the `DocumentElement` child node of `ParsedHtml`, otherwise you don't get any results at all. Also, the class string "dDoNo gsrt" does not equal "dDoNo", so you need to test if the value *contains* the class name "dDoNo".

Change

```
($WebResponse.ParsedHtml.GetElementsByTagName(‘div’) | Where {
    $_.ClassName -eq ‘dDoNo’
}).InnerText
```

to

```
($WebResponse.ParsedHtml.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName('div') | Where {
    $_.ClassName -match '\bdDoNo\b'
}).InnerText
```

and the code should do what you want.

Note that using typographic quotes (`’`) in code is not recommended. While they work most of the time I did encounter situations where they caused things to break in interesting ways. Use plain quotes instead (`'`).

Comment: Try `($WebResponse.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByTagName('div') | Where {$_.getAttributeNode('class').Value -match '\bdDoNo\b'}).InnerText
`

Comment: @Johannes When I ran the request from your question the returned result did not have a class "dDoNo" anywhere. Please double-check that the returned result actually contains what you're trying to match. Otherwise not getting a result wouldn't be all that surprising.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers That is really weird, I am inspecting the site with Chrome and finding the following element specified above <div class="dDoNo gsrt" style="margin-bottom:0;line-height:normal"><span data-dobid="hdw">text</span></div>